# How do I get this WHILE loop to work?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

Currently doing an exercise that I thought I had done right, using an IF ELSE statement, but once submitted I was told instead to use a WHILE or DO-WHILE loop, and I'm having a bit of trouble. You'll see where I've used the WHILE loop, but it is giving me an infinite loop of the error message that I assigned to it and I don't know how to make it stop!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal hours;
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5m;
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of hours parked:");
        hours = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        decimal parkingCost = hours * HOURLY_RATE;

        while (hours < 1 || hours > 24) 
        {
            Console.Write("Enter correct amount of hours - 1 to 24. ");
        }

        if (parkingCost > MAX_FEE) 
        {
            Console.Write("Total fee is $" + MAX_FEE);
            Console.WriteLine(" Time parked in hours is " + hours);
        }
        else
        {
            parkingCost = hours * HOURLY_RATE;
            Console.WriteLine("The cost of parking is " + parkingCost.ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("Time parked in hours is " + hours);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

So the idea is that I want for the "Enter correct amount of hours - 1 to 24. " to display if the user enters a number less than 1 or greater than 24, otherwise for the program to go ahead with the IF and ELSE statements.

Comment: ReadKey inside the loop, check entered char as numeric and between 1-24.  If it is, `break`.

Comment: You need to allow the user to correct an invalid entry. Put another `Console.ReadLine()` to collect a new version of `hours` inside the while loop, otherwise you'll loop forever on your  first error.

Comment: Thanks John. I added the code as per below answer, but I get a new issue: This while loop you provided worked wonders, up until one point. When I enter a wrong amount of hours, lets say 25, and then it asks me to enter the correct amount of hours, at which point any input provides the answer of MAX_FEE ($20). Is there a way around that? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the line accepting input inside the while loop as shown below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    decimal hours;
    const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5m;
    const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of hours parked:");
    hours = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    decimal parkingCost = hours * HOURLY_RATE;

    while (hours < 1 || hours > 24) 
    {
        Console.Write("Enter correct amount of hours - 1 to 24. ");
        hours = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }


    parkingCost = hours * HOURLY_RATE; // to recalculate

    if (parkingCost > MAX_FEE) 
    {
        Console.Write("Total fee is $" + MAX_FEE);
        Console.WriteLine(" Time parked in hours is " + hours);
    }
    else
    {
        parkingCost = hours * HOURLY_RATE;
        Console.WriteLine("The cost of parking is " + parkingCost.ToString("C"));
        Console.WriteLine("Time parked in hours is " + hours);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to read the value in the while loop again to get a new value:

```
    while (hours < 1 || hours > 24) 
    {
        Console.Write("Enter correct amount of hours - 1 to 24. ");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of hours parked:");
        hours = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Or as a Do While you can get rid of the first read and only loop on error

```
do {
   Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of hours parked:");
   try{
     hours = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     if(hours <1 || hours > 24) 
        Console.Write("Enter correct amount of hours - 1 to 24. ");
   } 
   catch { Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid numeric value"); }
} while(hours < 1 || hours > 24);
```

I added the try catch because if they enter a value that is not numeric it can throw an error.

Comment: This while loop you provided worked wonders, up until one point. When I enter a wrong amount of hours, lets say 25, and then it asks me to enter the correct amount of hours, at which point any input provides the answer of MAX_FEE ($20). Is there a way around that?

Comment: @LegendIsReal you should calculate your `parkingCost` after parsing the `hours`. move the `decimal parkingCost = hours * HOURLY_RATE;` "after" and "outside"  the `do-while` loop

Comment: Exactly what Paolo said.  Move the calculations after the while loop